# Flask-sqlalchemy Rowproxy cannot be modified

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to update records 'status' from my database where the 'sendtime' is in the past. I am receiving a set of records that I can iterate over and see all their fields with no issue. The issue arises when I attempt to update the status field.

The following results in **Rowproxy does not support item assignment**:

```
query = ('SELECT * FROM jobs '
    'WHERE status="INCOMPLETE" '
    'AND sendtime <= NOW()')
overdueJobs = db.engine.execute(query).fetchall()
for overdueJob in overdueJobs:
    overdueJob.status = "COMPLETE"
db.session.commit()
```

I read [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588375/can-i-assign-values-in-rowproxy-using-the-sqlalchemy) based on the error above and while converting to a dict allows me to edit the fields without errors, it does not actually commit anything to the database.

I believe I am doing something wrong regarding how I use the queried results. I think I have to use my **jobs** model somehow to access the fields, but the documentation and other questions I found on SO are for a single result from a query. What I have can be more than that. How do I edit the fields of each record returned from this query?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948189/flask-sql-alchemy-raw-query-instead-of-class-method).

I needed to modify my query from

```
overdueJobs = db.engine.execute(query).fetchall()
```

To

```
overdueJobs = jobs.query.from_statement(db.text(query)).all()
```

Where `jobs` is a model in my database. Then I could access each row as a model by looping over the returned result.